# WCF Rest Service Sharepoint hosted gives 401 unauthorized

Tags: rest, wcf, sharepoint, http-status-code-401

I have a sharepoint 2013 based intranet with NTLM Authentication. I have a WCF rest service developed and hosted on Sharepoint mapped folder. I need to call this WCF Rest service from another product. NTLM credentials passing is not an option. It allows Basic Authentication which is turned off on my Sharepoint intranet and turning it on is not an option.

If I make call without turning on the basic authentication, it gives me 401 unauthorized error. Which is expected.

What options do I have here to call the WCF Rest Service ?

Any type of settings on IIS _vti_Bin folder which can be done to call the WCF Service ?

Comment: Either you provide Windows credentials when invoking, or you turn off Windows authentication on the server-side. I think both of them can solve the problem.

Comment: Right. Already knew this one. Dont think it is possible. Just wanted to cover all parts ie anything which I might have left. Thanks for the response though !